# How to use QUERY in expdp to extract only the last 3 months data

Tags: oracle, expdp

In my other thread, I have asked how to extract only the last 3 months. However, I managed to extract data from the  last 3 months only from one table and it extracted all data for other tables. I have several tables in my schema and the column names for the timestamp are different.

In my par file I have the following QUERY but it did not work. I got ORA-00911 error message. I would like to know if the syntax of the below query is correct/possible .

```
    QUERY=TABLE1,TABLE2:"where TABLE1_STARTTIME >= TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') and TABLE2_STARTIME >= TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy');"
```

Comment: I don't know expdp but the error `ORA-00911` suggests invalic character. I would suggest you to recreate the same query in db to see if it is working.

Comment: I'd guess that you don't want the semicolon at the end of the query string.  If you remove that, does the error disappear?

Comment: Actually, your date function `TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')` doesn't work in oracle. I don't know if that was your problem. But try `TO_DATE('01/08/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')` and let see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

> QUERY=TABLE1,TABLE2:"where ... TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy');"

**Remove** the semi-colon in the **QUERY** parameter.:

```
QUERY=TABLE1,TABLE2:"where TABLE1_STARTTIME >= TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') 
                     and TABLE2_STARTIME >= TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')"
```

On a side note:

Not directly related to your issue. But remember **TO_DATE** is **NLS dependent**. You should specify the **NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**, else your query might fail for a different nls_date_language.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language='FRENCH';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') FROM DUAL
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=ENGLISH') FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('01
-----------
01-AO█T -15
```

I would prefer using **ANSI Date literal**, when you do not have any **time portion**. It is **NLS independent**. It uses a fixed format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language='FRENCH';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT DATE '2015-08-01' FROM DUAL;

DATE'2015-0
-----------
01-AO█T -15

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language='AMERICAN';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT DATE '2015-08-01' FROM DUAL;

DATE'2015
---------
01-AUG-15
```

Comment: hi all, thanks for all your feedbacks. I will try them out and let you know. thanks!

Comment: Hi all, what weird is that it worked when the query is done only on one table.Ex.
QUERY=TABLE1:"where TABLE1_STARTTIME >= TO_DATE('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')"

Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am getting the following when the query contains the 2 tables:

ORA-00904: "TABLE1_STARTTIME" : identifier non valide

Comment: Hi all, any other ideas? Thanks in advance!