# Importing table using query parameter

Tags: oracle, import, aix

I am having problem importing a table using query parameter, The table containes 1 million row , however with the date condition there are about 500,000 rows so I want to import only them. however using the below its importing all the data. why ? are there something wrong in quotes?

```
impdp system/pass dumpfile=TEST.dmp directory=EXPORT logfile=ilog.log tables=schema.TEST_MHDM
query='schema.TEST_MHDM:"WHERE dateadded>'31-dec-2014'"'
```

The linked question probles was due to a semi column which i dont have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use QUERY in expdp to extract only the last 3 months data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161901/how-to-use-query-in-expdp-to-extract-only-the-last-3-months-data)

Comment: @t.s. ill check the question however i am not getting any oerror also i didnt include this into parameter file

Comment: The problem was due to semi column can you semi column in my question?

Comment: I don't see the semicolon, but I see quoting and date formatting. You should use that question/answer to follow the pattern